# How to get an placeholder underneath the link for my opencart website in messengers?

Tags: seo, opencart

Using telegram, viber and facebook messenger I have noticed that links I share with my friends, have preview.
Sending links to my website via messengers doesn't create any preview/thumbnails (except index page).
Thanks in advance.
[Thumbnail example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbib9.png)

Answer (score 0):

there is 2 approaches to have your pages being shown in the telegram posts:

1. create a channel and publish your content in it and share the post's deeplink with your friends/customers:
   t.me/channelname/postOrder
   (e.g. [t.me/telegram/22](http://t.me/telegram/22))
2. there is a concept called "instant view" which tries to interpret pages of websites based on the predefined templates. you should login on https://instantview.telegram.org/my/ and define a template for you website's subpages, so telegram will know which part of your pages are important and in which format they should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an extension. Something like this https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=6182

**Notice**: I am not affiliate of any kind with the previous extension.